# How to remove time in datepicker

Tags: flutter, dart, datepicker

[image]

```
 MaterialButton(
   onPressed: _showDatePicker,
   color: Colors.blue,
   child: const Text(
      'choose date',
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25),
   ),
 ),
```

```
  //date picker
  DateTime _dateTime = DateTime(2020);

  void _showDatePicker() {
    showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: DateTime(2020, 1, 1),
      firstDate: DateTime(2020),
      lastDate: DateTime(2023),
    ).then((value) {
      setState(() {
        _dateTime = value!;
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package and do this:

```
void _showDatePicker() {
    showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: DateTime(2020, 1, 1),
      firstDate: DateTime(2020),
      lastDate: DateTime(2023),
    ).then((value) {
      if (value != null) {
        var result = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(value);
        setState(() {
          _dateTime = result;
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: please explain why is the ! here :
```_dateTime = result!;```

Comment: no need to !, I correct it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
DateTime(date.year, date.month, date.day)
```

or just use

```
DateUtils.dateOnly(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to use this to format this date the way you want it
https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html

Answer (score 0):

`showDatePicker` provide nullable DateTime on return.

```
Future<DateTime?> showDatePicker({
```

That's why when we are assigning value on `_dateTime` you need to use ! Unless we null check 1st. `!` means we say this value is not null.

Directly using `!` will crash the app when user press cancel button on date picker. If you like to check the error, remove if condition and use `!` directly.

```dart
  DateTime _dateTime = DateTime(2020);
  void _showDatePicker() {
    showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: DateTime(2020, 1, 1),
      firstDate: DateTime(2020),
      lastDate: DateTime(2023),
    ).then((value) {
      if (value != null) { 
        setState(() {
          _dateTime = value;
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

To remove time from text you can use

```dart
  Text("${_dateTime.year} ${_dateTime.month} ${_dateTime.day} "),
```

Also using intel package provide more option.

Comment: Glad to help, also use `!` only when you know the value isnt null